# How to disable mongod journal pre-allocation

Tags: mongodb, journal, pre-allocation

Is there a way to prevent mongod from pre-allocating these 100 MB files in journal folder?

WiredTigerPreplog.0000000001
WiredTigerPreplog.0000000002

I want journaling to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I often need to run test instances of mongod, and these preallocated WiredTiger journal (log) files just waste 200MB each time.

They can disabled by adding this parameter to your `mongod` command line:

```
--wiredTigerEngineConfigString 'log=(prealloc=false)'
```

Or this to your `mongod.conf` file:

```
storage:
    wiredTiger:
        engineConfig:
            configString: log=(prealloc=false)
```

Of course this should never be done in production, and only when testing things that are unrelated to journalling.  Journal file preallocation is a deliberate performance feature, which is almost always a win in the real world (and so is why it defaults to `true`).

Comment: Is there a way to reduce their size? 100MB for each file is a lot for small raspberry-pi projects.

Answer (score 0):

Find below some notes from MongoDB Documentation for [Journaling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/#journal-files)

> WiredTiger will pre-allocate journal files.
>
> **Preallocation Lag**
>
> MongoDB may preallocate journal files if the mongod process determines
>   that it is more efficient to preallocate journal files than create new
>   journal files as needed.

The preallocation can be avoided using only for MMapv1 storage engine using [--noprealloc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-noprealloc) option when starting the mongod. But this is not applicable for `wiredtiger` storage engine.

few more references

[Meaning of WiredTigerPreplog files](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/kS2kBssQdLM)